# Are the symptoms of 4 yugas visible on higher planetary systems?

Tags: yuga

We know the [symptoms of each of the 4 yugas](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/3) and pillars of religion(truthfulness, mercy, austerity and cleanliness) reduce with each passing yuga.

Are these symptoms to be seen only on earth or even in other planetary systems?

Comment: Who voted to close this question on opinion based, please leave a comment before closing!

Comment: It is even said in Puranas, four yugas are seen only in Bharatavarsha.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Write answer with references..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puranas say four Yugas are restricted to Bharata Varsha alone. In chapters which describe Bharata and four Yugas, many Puranas say only Bharatavarsha has division of four Yugas.

***Chapter 16***, Description of Bharata, Anusanga of Brahmanda Purana says:

> 68b-69. Sages have said that there are four Yugas, in the Bhårata"
>   sub-continent, viz. Krta, Tretá, Dväpara and Tişya (Kali). I shall
>   mention their detailed divisions wholly later on.

***Chapter 29***, Cycle of Yugas: Characteristic of four Yugas, Anusanga also says same.

> 23. Wise persons and sages have said that there are four Yugas in Bhārata subcontinent<sup>[1]</sup>. They are Krta, Treta, Dvāpara and Kali.

Translator says in footnotes

> 1. It is strange that Yugas should be restricted to India (Bhårata) only.

***Chapter 18***, Umasamhita of Shiva Purana says:

> चत्वारि भारते वर्षे युगान्यासन्महामुने। 
>  कृतादीनि न चान्येषु
>   द्वीपेषु प्रभवन्ति हि।।१५।।
>
> 15. O great sage, all the four Yugas Krta and others are followed in Bhärata and not in the other Dvipas.

***Chapter 3***, Book 2 of Vishnu Purana says:

> चत्वारि भारत वर्षे युगान्यत्र महामुने।। 
>  कृतं त्रेता द्वापश्च
>   कलिश्चान्यत्र न क्वचित्॥ १९॥
>
> In the Bhārata-varsa it is that the succession of four Yugas or ages,
>   the Krta the Treta. The Dvăpara, and Kali, takes place;

***Chapter 7***, Swarga Khanda of Padma Purana says:

> Suta said:
>  3-8. There are four yugas in Bharatavarsa. The first
>   yuga was Krta; then there was Tretayuga, O brahmanas. After that
>   Dvapara sets in; then comes Kali.

***Chapter 114***, Part 1 of Matsya Purana says:

> चत्वारि भारते वर्षे युगानि मुनयोऽब्रुवन्। 
>  कृतं त्रेता द्वापरं च
>   कलिश्चेति चतुर्युगम्। 
>  तेषां निसर्गं वक्ष्यामि उपरिष्टाच्च
>   कृत्स्नशः॥५७॥
>
> There are four ages in Bharatavarsha viz.- Satya, Tretā, Dvăpara and
>   Kaliyuga. I am now going to give you an account of each.

One can observe repetition of  phrase *चत्वारि भारते वर्षे युगानि (catvāri bhārate varṣe yugāni)* in many Purana. Even description of Bharata and four Yugas is similar in many Puranas.

Comment: I will update quotes from other Puranas soon.

Comment: This is interesting that Yugas apply on Bharatavarsha only

Comment: @Rickross Yes. Puranas unanimously declare only Bharata has four Yugas.

Comment: You may be interested in [sub classification of Sri Yukteswar Yuga theory](https://www.vedanet.com/keys-to-the-yugas-or-cycles-of-the-ages-subyugas-in-the-sri-yukteswar-yuga-cycle/) which does explain events happening all around the globe as per the running Yuga.

Comment: Bharata varsa then can't be only India. Because Kali yuga symptoms can seen in other places.

Comment: @RaRe It could be. I think ISKCON believes Bharta Varsha is entire earth. Btw, in Puranas other dvipas are described as Bhoga Bhumis and places of sensual enjoyments. I'm not sure personally.

Comment: I don't limit my view to ISKCON's always b/c in  these types of matters no one is expert. Other continents appear bhoga bhumis now b/c of scientific advancement. Other wise many were tribals, theives before.. Other dvipas are described as surrounded by sugarcane, liquor, butter, milk oceans etc.. Atleast I believe Jambudvipa(has 9 varshas) is greater than earth and bharata varsa is earth. One more reason is b/c residents of other 8 varshas of Jambudvipa are said to remain young always and die. What I am not sure: is there any diff b/w bharata varsa and bharata khanda or are they synonymous?

Answer (score 3):

Only Bhārata Varsha is affected by Yuga cycle. Moreover, this is Karma Bhumi in the sense, here you can perform some deeds. People born in other countries are just experiencing their previous deds. From Mrgendra Agama chapter 13

> Those who are living in the Bharata varsha are subjected to changes and deviations occurring in the matters related to knowledge, longevity, complexion, strength, wealth and  descendants **according to the nature of the cyclic yugas.** For the food, they are eating those which are obtained by ploughing and  by the works other than ploughing. They are affected by three kinds of miseries – adhyatmika, adhibhautika and adhidaivika. **But, there is one specific quality for this Bharta varsha. Whatever be the deeds of the people, the fruits of their deeds are never experienced here; they are experienced in other worlds.** Because, all other worlds are considered to be the regions related to the fruits only(phala bhumi). Bharata varsha is the land of  deeds only (karma bhumi). Verse 93

Personally, I think whole earth is Bhārata Varsha but don't have any clue about where other countries and continents are!

Comment: @RaRe  Likewise [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_cosmology)

Comment: Good job Sig but whole earth is not BB